# Query Table using Table Names or MetaTables - LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

Is there a way to use Meta Tales or Table names to Construct a dynamic query in LINQ?

```
foreach (var metaTable in db.Mapping.GetTables())
{
    var queryType = metaTable.RowType.Type;

    var test = from q in db.GetTable(queryType)
               select q;
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this? The attempt above yields the error:

Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.Linq.ITable'.  'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'q'.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: This loop should be able to select all from each table in the data context

Comment: The short answer is "yes", but you'll probably have to do a lot of things like `MakeGenericMethod`...

Comment: Can you post the long answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "long answer" is a lot of nasty expression code: You have to build up the expression tree for your query from scratch because the compiler only does it if everything is strongly typed. However if you just want to get all rows, just write

```
var test = db.GetTable(queryType).Cast<object>();
```

because the ITable interface is already IEnumerable. Now you still need to make sense of a sequence of untyped objects.

Can you tell us what you want to do and why?

Comment: I'm trying to build a dynamic custom query based on the data context. Also thanks for your answer it is really helpful. I believe with that and the parameter names create queries based on the users input.

Comment: Google for linq dynamic query. There is some help available for constructing queries from strings like query.OrderBy("fieldName")

Answer (score 1):

Have you included a reference to the System.Data.Linq namespace? If that is missing you then you'd probably get this error as I think the LINQ extension methods come from that.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The code posted in the question should work as is.